# Cwac Camera add thumnail image

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I want to thumbnail image on camera view with cwac library.
[image]

```
cameraFragment.takePicture();

            Bitmap bitmap = Utility.decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(
                    cameraFragment.cameraHost.getPhotoPath()
                            .getAbsolutePath(), 120, 120);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: i want to show the thumbnail of taken picture like default camera app. How do i do:))

Comment: Note that this has nothing much to do with the CWAC-Camera library, as you could be wanting to "show the thumbnail" of an image from anywhere, and the code would not be significantly different. What specifically is your problem with the code you have, other than trying to read the picture before it is ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution:
I dont use cwac camera library.Use custom camera layout.
[Kut Camera](https://github.com/devcelebi/Kut-Camera)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Cwac, my work was too advanced to switch to another library, so my solution is here.

Modify your CameraFragment.onCreate method to set your DemoCameraHost as default host:

```
public class CameraFragment extends com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment {
private DemoCameraHost mDemoCamHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mDemoCamHost = new DemoCameraHost(getActivity());
    this.setHost(mDemoCamHost);
}
```

In DemoCameraHost method useSingleShotMode must return `false`.

```
/**
* Method indicates if after taking picture bitmap is frozen or next frame shown.
*
* @return Enable showing preview, must be false for this project.
*/
@Override
public boolean useSingleShotMode() {
    return false;
}
```

Now you must override saveImage method in DemoCameraHost where you receive imaged encoded as byte array, just decode it back:

```
@Override
public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, byte[] image) {
    Log.i(TAG, "saveImage");
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    //drawOnTop.setBitmap(bm); // this is my internal class that operates on the bitmap
    if (bm == null)
        Log.e(TAG, "bitmap is null");
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "bitmap size: " + bm.getWidth() + ":" + bm.getHeight());

    // dont'save image on SD, prevents delay and freezing screen
    //super.saveImage(xact, image);
}
```

Now when you call `takePicture()` from CameraFragment you will get:

```
 04-06 11:47:12.576    3038-3038/net.agilob.ssocv I/CamFrg﹕ useSingleShotMode
 04-06 11:47:12.596    3038-3130/net.agilob.ssocv I/CamFrg﹕ saveImage
 04-06 11:47:12.676    3038-3130/net.agilob.ssocv E/CamFrg﹕ bitmap size: 1280:960
```